# Merge several dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have got multiple (n) dataframes with variable row lengths and 3 columns each. I just want the first column of each dataframe, so i dropped the others using df.drop.
I want to merge them into one dataframe with n columns. 
I used pd.concat for merging.

```
    df1.drop(columns=['col2' ,'col3']).to_csv('df1.csv', sep=';')

    df2.drop(columns=['col2', 'col3']).to_csv('df2.csv', sep=';')

pd.concat([pd.concat([df1.drop(columns=['col2','col3']),
                      df2.drop(columns=['col2','col3'])] ,axis=1)])\
                        .to_csv('merged.csv', sep=';')
```

It gives me following Output as csv File:

```
    col1 (df1)  col1 (df1)
0   0.0 
1   0.055   
2   0.096   
3   0.131   
2074        70.997
2075        71.002
2076        71.065
2077        71.101
```

So u see it just adds the columns as rows. While for example row 3 is in column 2 empty. and row 2074 in colum 1 empty.
I thought axis = 1 would fix this but it doesnt.

Expected Output:

```
col1 (df1)        col1 (df1)
0   0.0             70.997
1   0.055           71.002
2   0.096           71.065
3   0.131           71.101
```

If I try `axis = 1, ignoreIndex=True` my column names changes to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need same index values in both DataFrames created by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and parameter `reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1['col1'].reset_index(drop=True), 
                 df2['col1'].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
df3.columns = ['col1 (df1)','col1 (df2)']
print (df3)
   col1 (df1)  col1 (df2)
0       0.000      70.997
1       0.055      71.002
2       0.096      71.065
3       0.131      71.101
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the index of df2 as same as df1

```
df2.index=df1.index
df1['col1(df2)']=df2.col1
df1.rename(columns={'col1':'col1(df1)'})
Out[7]: 
   col1(df1)  col1(df2)
0      0.000     70.997
1      0.055     71.002
2      0.096     71.065
3      0.130     71.101
```